# Fastest way to load an animated GIF in Python into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

Surprisingly I couldn't see any coverage of this.

I've found 3 recognised ways of performing this - Pillow, OpenCV, and Imageio.  The results surprised me, so I've posted them as a self-answering Q&A (below).

Comment: welcome. asking for "the best" is still asking for recommendations (of libraries), which is off-topic. please review [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code using Pillow is very inefficient!  `Image`s are compatibable with [Numpy's array interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html) so your conversion code is complicating things.

I'd use the following helper to get the frames out into a Numpy array:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import numpy as np

def load_frames(image: Image, mode='RGBA'):
    return np.array([
        np.array(frame.convert(mode))
        for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(image)
    ])

with Image.open('animated.gif') as im:
    frames = load_frames(im)
```

This runs in basically the same time as the others.  For example, with a 400x400 pixel, 21 frame, GIF I have, it takes mimread ~140ms, while Pillow takes ~130ms.

Update: I've just had a play with CV2 and noticed its "wall clock" time is better (i.e. what you were measuring) because it's doing work in other threads.  For example, if I run using the [Jupyter `%time` magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time), I get the following output:

ImageIO

```
CPU times: user 135 ms, sys: 9.81 ms, total: 145 ms
Wall time: 145 ms
```

PIL

```
CPU times: user 127 ms, sys: 3.03 ms, total: 130 ms
Wall time: 130 ms
```

CV2

```
CPU times: user 309 ms, sys: 95 ms, total: 404 ms
Wall time: 89.7 ms
```

I.e. although it's finishing the loop in 90ms, it's used ~4.5x that CPU time in total.

So if you're interested in the time to complete for a single large image, you might want to use CV2.  But if you were batch processing lots of images, I'd suggest using Pillow in a [multiprocessing `Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the standard way of loading a GIF in each library:

```
import os
import cv2
import time
import imageio
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

gifs = glob(os.path.join("/folder/of/gifs", "*"))
print(f"Found {len(gifs)} GIFs")

def load_gif_as_video_pil(gif_path):
    im = Image.open(gif_path)
    frames = []
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
        frame = np.array(frame.copy().convert('RGB').getdata(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(frame.size[1],
                                                                                        frame.size[0],
                                                                                        3)
        frames.append(frame)

    return np.array(frames)

def load_gif_as_video_imageio(gif_path):
    return imageio.mimread(gif_path)

def load_gif_as_video_opencv(filename):
    gif = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
    frames = []
    while True:
        ret, frame = gif.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frames.append(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    return np.array(frames)


start = time.time()
[load_gif_as_video_imageio(path) for path in tqdm(gifs)]
end = time.time()
print(f"ImageIO: {end - start}")

start = time.time()
[load_gif_as_video_opencv(path) for path in tqdm(gifs)]
end = time.time()
print(f"OpenCV: {end - start}")

start = time.time()
[load_gif_as_video_pil(path) for path in tqdm(gifs)]
end = time.time()
print(f"PIL: {end - start}")
```

Over 250 GIFs, these are the results:

```
100%|██████████| 250/250 [00:13<00:00, 18.32it/s]
ImageIO: 13.829721689224243
100%|██████████| 250/250 [00:06<00:00, 39.04it/s]
OpenCV: 6.478164434432983
100%|██████████| 250/250 [03:00<00:00,  1.38it/s]
PIL: 181.03292179107666
```

OpenCV is twice as fast as imageio, which is 15x faster than PIL (using my method, anyway).